# Is there an efficient way to concatenate many nested vectors in c++

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

I want to be able to concatenate nested vectors in c++ efficiently in a specific way as shown below:

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> a = {{1,2,3},{6,7,8},{9,10,11}};
std::vector<float> b;
//wanted: b = {1,6,9,
//             2,7,10,
//             3,8,11};

uint32_t inside = 3;
//this variable would also be known
```

This result would be achieved doing the following:

```
uint32_t inside = 3;
std::vector<float> b(inside*a.size());
uint32_t counter = 0;
for(uint32_t i = 0; i < inside; i++){
    for(uint32_t j = 0; j < a.size(); j++){
        b.at(counter) = a.at(j).at(i);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

However, I would like it if I could achieve it using something faster than nested for loops, and that is more memory efficient. Something like the following, (but this obviously would not work):

```
std::vector<float> b;
b.reserve(inside*a.size());
for(uint32_t i = 0; i < inside; i++){
    std::move(a.begin()[i], a.end()[i], std::back_inserter(b));
}
```

Is there anything built-in to c++ vectors that might be able to do this more efficiently than the code I have above?

~EDIT~

So to explain better, I basically want to take the first element from each vector inside `a`, and then add it to `b`. Then, I want to do that for the second element inside each vector in `a`, and so on. As shown with the desired result in the first block of code.

Comment: `a.begin()[i]` doesn't do what you think it does: It actually refers to the begin vector that has been incremented `i` times, which is why `a.end()[i]` is UB for any `i` > 0.

Comment: You want `a[i].begin()`, `a[i].end()`, and to use `a.size()` for your loop condition in your second example.  Complexity wise it's exactly the same as the first (though it likely has significant micro-optimization that would make it perform slightly better).

Comment: Probably `std::vector<float> b; b.reserve(inside*a.size()); for (auto& inner : a) { b.insert(b.end(), inner.begin(), inner.end()); }` Perhaps you could also move the first inner vector into `b` before calling `reserve` to allow for the possibility of not requiring any reallocations, if capacity of the first inner vector is sufficient to store all values.

Comment: So these would work if i just wanted to concatenate all the vectors in order. However, my goal is to take the first element from each vector and add it inside of `b`. Then the second element, and so on. I will edit my post and explain that better.

Comment: Sounds like you want `zip_view` then

Comment: Sounds like there is no way around 2 loops. You can use range-for in the inner loop and `std::back_inserter` instead of your `counter` though.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: `at` checks if the index exists. We can just go for it and use `operator[]` which doesn't perform such a check.

Next it's important to realize what the memory structure of nested vectors looks like. The inner elements will be stored sequentially so we should swap the loops, to avoid cache misses:

```
uint32_t inside = 3;
std::vector<float> b(inside*a.size());
for(uint32_t j = 0; j < a.size(); j++){
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < inside; i++){
        b[j + i * inside] = a[j][i];
    }
}
```

I didn't time it but I suspect this should already go faster.

Finally,

if the inner size is really only 3, we should [unroll the loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling) altogether.

Comment: If it's a compile time constant then then make it a const and let the compiler unroll the loop. And if it isn't a fundamental type then `std::move` could be helpful.